# Finding a value in ByteString (which is actually JSON)

Tags: json, haskell

A web service returns a response as `ByteString`

```
  req <- parseUrl "https://api.example.com"
  res <- withManager $ httpLbs $ configReq req
  case (HashMap.lookup "result" $ responseBody res) of .... -- error - responseBody returns ByteString


  where 
    configReq r = --......
```

To be more specific, `responseBody` returns data in `ByteString`, although it's actually valid JSON. I need to find a value in it. Obviously, it would be easier to find it if it was JSON and not `ByteString`.

If that's the case, how do I convert it to JSON?

UPDATE:

```
decode $ responseBody resp :: IO (Either String Aeson.Value)
```

error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `IO (Either String Value)'
                with actual type `Maybe a0'
```

Comment: Your question title is about finding a value in a bytestring, but the problem you need to solve is converting that bytestring into JSON.  Have you tried googling for "haskell bytestring json"?  For me, the first result is the documentation for the `aeson` package on hackage, which is the standard library for manipulating JSON.  It has a function `Data.Aeson.decode :: FromJSON a => ByteString -> Maybe a` that is what you're looking for.

Comment: [Here's a really simple example](https://gist.github.com/bheklilr/98ac8f8e663cf02fcaa6) of converting JSON to a custom data type, which might give you an idea of how to do what you want to do.

Comment: @bheklilr, that's what I wanted to avoid: creating a matching data type. I don't want to create a data type only for parsing json, I want to be able to parse it to something where I can apply HashTable.lookup later.

Comment: @bheklilr, actually to `:: IO (Either String Aeson.Value)`

Comment: Loading to a custom data type is pretty common, so I went with that approach, but `Data.Aeson` has a default data type of `Value` that represents plain JSON data that you can cast to.  You can then manipulate the document as you would expect to be able to, with an ADT for each type of value (object, array, string, number, bool, or null) and `Object` is defined as `HashMap Text Value`.

Comment: @bheklilr, take a look at my update please. I tried different variants but it still didn't compile.

Comment: The function `decode` has the type of `FromJSON a => ByteString -> Maybe a`, you'll need to extract the `ByteString` from `responseBody resp` and feed that into `decode`.  You can't feed the the `Either String ByteString` directly into `decode`, the types don't line up.

Comment: @bheklilr That's what I'm doing: I'm extracting BytString from responseBody.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56448/discussion-between-bheklilr-and-grienders).

Answer (score 2):

You'll find several resources for converting bytestring to JSON. The simplest use cases are on the hackage page itself, and the rest you can infer using type signatures of the entities involved.

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.7.0.6/docs/Data-Aeson.html

But here's a super quick intro to JSON with Aeson:
In most languages, you have things like this:

```
someString = '{ "name" : ["value1", 2] }'
aDict = json.loads(someString)
```

This is obviously great, because JSON has a nearly one to one mapping with a fundamental data-structure of the language. Containers in most dynamic languages can contain values of any type, and so moving from JSON to data structure is a single step.

However, that is not the case with Haskell. You can't put things of arbitrary types into a container like type (A list, or a dictionary).

So Aeson does a neat thing. It defines an intermediate Haskell type for you, that maps directly to JSON.

A fundamental unit in `Aeson` is a `Value`. The Value can contain many things. Like an integer, string, an array, or an object.

[https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.7.0.6/docs/Data-Aeson.html#t:Value](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.7.0.6/docs/Data-Aeson.html#t%3aValue)

An aeson array is a `Vector` (like a list but better) of `Value`s and an aeson object is a `HashMap` of `Text` to `Value`s

The next interesting step is that you can define functions that will convert an Aeson value to your Haskell type. This completes the loop. `ByteString` to `Value` to a custom type.

So all you do is implement `parseJSON` and `toJSON` functions that convert aeson Values to your type and vice-versa. The bit that converts a bytestring into a valid aeson value is implemented by aeson. So the heavy lifting is all done.

Just important to note, that Aeson bytestring is a lazy bytestring, so you might need some strict to lazy helpers.

```
stringToLazy :: String -> ByteString
stringToLazy x = Data.Bytestring.Lazy.fromChunks [(Data.ByteString.Char8.pack x)]

lazyToString :: ByteString -> String
lazyToString x = Data.ByteString.Char8.unpack $ Data.ByteString.Char8.concat $ Data.ByteString.Lazy.toChunks
```

That should be enough to get started with Aeson.

--

Common decoding functions with Aeson:

```
decode :: ByteString -> Maybe YourType
eitherDecode :: ByteString -> Either String YourType.
```

In your case, you're looking for eitherDecode.